# How does the command "linux-boot-prober" work?

Tags: lvm

I have installed some Ubuntu on my LVM disks. In Ubuntu10.04, I rename the Ubuntu12.04's lv but the "linux-boot-probe" goes wrong.

Here is what I did:

```
sudo lvname LVMDisk Ubuntu12.04 LabUbuntu12.04 #I have installed Ubuntu12.04 on this lv
sudo linux-boot-prober /dev/mapper/LVMDisk-LabUbuntu12.04
```

The following is the result. We still can see `root=/dev/mapper/LVMDisk-Ubuntu12.04`.

It doesn't change? Why?

```
/dev/mapper/LVMDisk-LabUbuntu12.04:/dev/mapper/LVMDisk-LabUbuntu12.04:Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-30-generic-pae:/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-30-generic-pae:/boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-30-generic-pae:root=/dev/mapper/LVMDisk-Ubuntu12.04 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
/dev/mapper/LVMDisk-LabUbuntu12.04:/dev/mapper/LVMDisk-LabUbuntu12.04:Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-30-generic-pae (recovery mode):/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-30-generic-pae:/boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-30-generic-pae:root=/dev/mapper/LVMDisk-Ubuntu12.04 ro recovery nomodeset
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer for my own question. The command read the `boot/grub/grub.cfg` or `boot/grub/menu.lst` on the device to look for the information.

Comment: and you get details of what it did in /var/log/syslog, afaik.

Comment: it will read /etc/fstab on the target partition to know whether /boot is mounted from another location, too. That may raise issues when trying to update a system with multiple OS all mounting the same /boot.